# which one is fast load data infile or normal insertion?

Tags: mysql, insert, bulkinsert, load-data-infile

I have a table with 40 million records, and I want to copy this 40M into 80M like this-

```
INSERT INTO cdr (id,dataPacketDownLink, dataPacketUpLink,dataPlanEndTime,dataPlanStartTime,dataVolumeDownLink,dataVolumeUpLink,
dataplan,dataplanType, createdOn, deviceName, duration, effectiveDuration, HOUR, eventDate, msisdn, QUARTER, validDays, dataLeft,completedOn,evedate)SELECT null,dataPacketDownLink, dataPacketUpLink,dataPlanEndTime,dataPlanStartTime,dataVolumeDownLink,dataVolumeUpLink,
dataplan,dataplanType, createdOn, deviceName, duration, effectiveDuration, HOUR, eventDate, msisdn, QUARTER, validDays, dataLeft,completedOn,eve_date FROM cdr;
```

is it correct to use this one or I should use SELECT INTO OUTFILE and LOAD DATA INFILE for fast insertion?
Or is there any better procedure than above two?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't have a benchmark for your specific configuration but I think your current solution is the best. (no disk write/reads in the middle of the process)

Comment: thank you sebas for quick response.
I have already started this and its been 3hours and insertion is not done yet, so i am thinking about aborting the insertion. Is it normal to take such time? I am using 4GB RAM on 32 bit machine.

Comment: Well how big are the fields of this table? Mysql is creating a temporary table of 40M rows due to the fact it selects from the same table it is inserting. If you wana try something different, I'll add another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the big TEMPORARY TABLE created implicitely in this operation (inserting into the table being selected), you can try this option:

```
CREATE TABLE cdr2 AS
SELECT dataPacketDownLink, dataPacketUpLink,dataPlanEndTime,dataPlanStartTime,dataVolumeDownLink,dataVolumeUpLink,
dataplan,dataplanType, createdOn, deviceName, duration, effectiveDuration, HOUR, eventDate, msisdn, QUARTER, validDays, dataLeft,completedOn,evedate 
FROM cdr
UNION ALL
SELECT dataPacketDownLink, dataPacketUpLink,dataPlanEndTime,dataPlanStartTime,dataVolumeDownLink,dataVolumeUpLink,
dataplan,dataplanType, createdOn, deviceName, duration, effectiveDuration, HOUR, eventDate, msisdn, QUARTER, validDays, dataLeft,completedOn,evedate 
FROM cdr;

ALTER TABLE cdr2 ADD COLUMN (id INT(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT)
```

once you checked that everything is ok in cdr2, you may:

- `DROP TABLE cdr`
- `RENAME TABLE cdr2 TO cdr`

Don't forget to add the missing indexes to the new table.

Comment: Hi sebas,
I have read even tested this thing that adding index into 80million around records gonna take lot of time. Your solution is also good, but i think i have already waited for 3 hour, so now i think should wait a little. :)

Comment: wait there is one more thing i want to share that,] i used this command yesterday night, and i thought that my system is not gonna sleep. but it was, today i came and see after resuming my system that its still going on. Is there something wrong because of system sleep?

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: win 7 32 bit 4 gb ram

Comment: well I suppose that during the sleeping time nothing has been done, except screwing with the RAM!

Comment: means its still working correct? or its already screwed and i have to abort it? but it didn't take that much time when i insert 20million(1 and half hour) rows with the same method. than why its taking that much time?

Comment: I have no idea... You have to monitor the performances of your mysql database instance (CPU, Private bytes, virtual bytes)

Comment: how i can monitor? sorry for this question but I am a new guy and this is suppose to be my first assignment.

Comment: The sure thing is that you need a huge buffer for this kind of operation. It means you need a lot of RAM too. You could also investigate an insert select statement 1000k per 1000k rows, putting that in a while loop in a stored procedure (insert ... select ... limit x, x+1000, looping over x with a step of 1000). It would garantee using the ram and not the harddrive. But it is usually slower than plain insert select.

Answer (score 2):

You current solution is fairly good, but if your table has a lot of indexes, that might slow things down. Indexes are good for searching, but slow down insertion.

You could try dropping all (or most) of the indexes first, copy all data, and then re-create them. Alternatively, you could construct a new table without indexes, copy all the data there, create indexes on the new table and then drop the old table and rename the new table.

Nevertheless, I've seen modifications on tables this size taking this long before. It's unfortunate, but MySQL isn't very fast at these things.

Comment: you are right about index, but removing index is not a good idea, other wise altering table for adding index with double records gonna cause double time. All i am doing is waiting now to finish that insertion. Well thanks for the help. there are 2-3 indexes on the table.

Comment: If you leave the index on, changes are the index is updated for every row inserted. When you remove it, you'll have to add it later, which of course takes time as well, but it is a one time action, so in total it might be faster. Not saying that you should cancel your current operation, but if this is something you have to do on a regular basis, you might want to consider which is faster in total.

Comment: well this is helpful. I have to make a copy of this table too so when this operation is done I am gonna use this idea so i can figure out which one is really fast.